# Dropped frames in ffmpeg when adding an overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a white overlay box using ffmpeg to an mp4 file downloaded from YouTube. I know the syntax and it is working OK with small videos, but I'm struggling to get it to work in a longer one. This is the exact command:

`ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -strict -2 -vf "color=white:200x50 [over]; [in][over] overlay=250:320:enable=between(t\,0\,52) [out]" out.mp4`

Initially, it works like a charm:

```
$ ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -preset slow -strict -2 -vf "color=white:200x50 [over]; [in][over] overlay=250:320:enable=between(t\,0\,52) [out]" -t 60 out.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 26 2015 23:00:53 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=xv --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-vda --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2014-01-30 16:48:50
  Duration: 00:13:30.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 692 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 497 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-30 16:48:54
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x7fa8cb82fa00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x7fa8cb82fa00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fa8cb82fa00] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-30 16:48:54
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
      encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1500 fps= 47 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2518kB time=00:01:00.00 bitrate= 343.8kbits/s
```

But after some time, that command starts yelling dropped frames:

`frame=20269 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=   23283kB time=00:13:30.70 bitrate= 235.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=548431`

and it never ends. Any clue?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : thanks. Added a more verbose output (tried the -t 60 to limit the output, but with that small time-slice the conversion is working great, no dropped frames at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -strict -2 -vf "color=white:200x50 [over]; [in][over] overlay=250:320:enable=between(t\,0\,52):shortest=1 [out]" out.mp4
```

The primary input is of finite length, but the secondary input isn't, so it keeps on going. This shouldn't be happening. It ought to terminate when the primary input does, but I tested your command and could reproduce the behaviour you got. Adding the `shortest=1` avoids it.

Comment: The shortest=1 option did the trick! Thanks, you got my vote (and accepted answer) :)